# Show a label of x and y values, and possibly other values when hovering over a function with the mouse in GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way that when i hover over a function, say `f(x) = x**2`, that it pops up a label when i move my mouse onto the function at, say, `x=2`, it shows a label of `"x = 2 \n (new line) y = 4"` or something like that? Also if that is possible can I make it so that it includes external values? What i mean by this is if i have a gradient formula, for `x**2`, `2*x`, I can tell GNUPLOT to say below the x and y label values, "Gradient: 4". It doesn't have to be the derivative but that is just an example of what i mean.

Comment: sorry stack overflow bolded after "x2" that is supposed to be x^2 but with "**" syntax used in gnuplot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `hypertext`. In the gnuplot console check `help hypertext`.

If you move the mouse pointer close to a datapoint, some text will pop-up. It will be easier to "catch" the point and get the hypertext shown if you plot the labels with a pointsize a bit larger, e.g. `ps 3` and "invisible", i.e. `lt -2` which is the background color.
This works with an interactive wxt terminal. You need to check other terminals. Tested with gnuplot 5.2.6.

**Code:**

```
### add hypertext (wxt terminal)
reset session

# create some test data
set print $Data
do for [x=-5:5] {
    print sprintf("%g %g", x, x**2)
}
set print

plot $Data u 1:2:(sprintf("x=%g\ny=%g",$1,$2)) w labels hypertext point pt 7 ps 3 lt -2 notitle, \
        '' u 1:2 w lp pt 7 title "f(x)"

### end of code
```

**Result:** (screenshot)

[image]

**Addition:**

Example with more points and plotted `with lines`. There is no snapping to the curve, you have to move along the curve.

**Code:**

```
### add hypertext (wxt terminal)
reset session

# create some test data
set samples 201
set xrange[-5:5]
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:($1**2):(2*$1) w table
unset table

set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
plot $Data u 1:2:(sprintf("x=%.2f\ny=%.2f\ndy/dx=%.2f",$1,$2,$3)) w labels hypertext point pt 7 ps 1 lt -2 notitle, \
        '' u 1:2 w l lw 2 title "f(x)"
### end of code
```

**Result:** (screen capture)

[image]

**Addition2:** (using functions for interactive zoom-in)

**Code:**

```
### add hypertext (wxt terminal) with functions for interactive zoom-in
reset session

set xlabel 'x'
set xrange[-5:5]
set ylabel 'y'
set samples 201

f(x) = x**2
g(x) = 2*x

plot '+' u (x):(f(x)):(sprintf("x=%.2g\ny=%.2g\ndy/dx=%.2g",x,f(x),g(x))) w labels hypertext point pt 7 ps 1 lt -2 notitle, \
        f(x) w l lw 2 title "f(x)"
### end of code
```

Comment: thats pretty good, thanks. Just as an additional thing to add to that, is there a way to make it like in desmos, when you click on the function and move the mouse around it does those labels at the mouse x/y position, rather than a set of points? Also how would you implement a function to that label, ie, gradient, like underneath the y=9 put  like "gradient = 6" or something. Thanks

Comment: do you mean "continous"? well, you could take many more points. You don't have to plot the visible curve `with linespoints`, you could also do `with lines`. If you want to show the gradient of `x**2` then you could just take `sprintf("x=%g\ny=%g",$1,2*$1)`. If it is a more complicated function or dataset, there would different ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful. With the 'continuous' points i'd imagine it will get very laggy if i put too many, perhaps i could reset it every time the user zooms to create the illusion that there is always points for the label? What i mean is if there are 200 pts in a set axis, they zoom in to a certain part and then within that part if its the same size grid, put another 200 points for them to hover over? I wouldn't know how to do this so if you have any ideas about doing that it would be great!

Comment: OK. if you want to interactively zoom-in, then you have to use functions. A file or dataset would be fixed. If you use e.g. `set samples 200`. then after every zooming 200 new samples will be taken within the new range. I will add this to the answer.